# How can the storage space of an avatar be restricted to a standard size?

Tags: biology, physics, gods

An avatar is a mortal shell constructed to hold a godlike entity from a higher realm. Gods cannot pass into the human realm due to a mystical barrier that separates both realms. These avatars function as a bypass for a deity to allow them to walk among mortals, built by the followers of that deity. They are "landing zones" that provide a deity a place to be summoned into and inhabit and are built to specific instructions to be able to contain it. These avatars are 25 ft tall and must contain multiple compartments to house the soul of a god, which is massive. To fit into this body, a god must divide his soul into pieces to fit in their separate compartments, which are similar to cells built into the avatar's body. Once sealed into this mortal form, it can activate it as a shell to house its spirit.  Unfortunately, its large frame is inconvienent and somewhat cumbersome, and its goal is to find a way to squeeze into a smaller body which is more sufficient to use among humans. This so far has been unatainable.

As technology becomes more advanced, it has the ability to get smaller and more operable. The computers of WW2 were like a billion feet fall, taking up entire rooms to do the most basic things. Today, they are as small as a MacBook pro or even an apple watch, which are hundreds of times more powerful and efficient. As power and ability increases, the size of an object shrinks. This is even evident in the human body itself. A single strand of DNA can store up to 700 terabytes as it is incredibly dense as a storage medium. This is as large as a single droplet in your hand. The best solution would be to make smaller avatars with more numerous compartments. A smaller body could contain double the compartments of a larger avatar, increasing as needed. As the entity can divide its souls enough to allow it to fit into any frame, this should not a problem.

What would force an avatar to maintain the current standard size of its frame?

Comment: Can the soul have the physical properties of a liquid? "A liquid is a nearly incompressible fluid" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid so if the soul had a specific amount of liters then it would be forced to stay in the current standard size and cannot shrink.

Answer (score 1):

## Their soul is more like a car than a computer.

The avatar acts as a conduit, pipes to a higher realm, letting a small aspect of their soul enter the mortal realm and letting a material that shouldn't exist in the physical plane exist.

As such, it's not a lot smaller even with more advanced technology. It has greater capabilities, just as a modern car is faster than a 1930s car, but some great size is needed to power the engines of reality.

Answer (score 0):

Q: *"These avatars are 25 ft tall and must contain multiple compartments to house the soul of a god, which is massive. To fit into this body, a god must divide his soul into pieces to fit in their separate compartments, which are similar to cells built into the avatar's body"*

**Make sure you have lots of Gods**

Polytheism prevents the avatars to become too big. If you have a God of fishery, spit it in a God for mussel fisheries, a God for plaice fisheries, etcetera. Spread the burden !

**Each God should use avatar templates**

When a God's soul is bulky, don't attempt to provide a one-size-fits-all avatar. When the God is summoned, consider the reason why that happened. Inside the avatar, only the soul parts are stacked that are relevant to mediate and solve the problem.

Examples: Suppose your God of Conflict is summoned. When there is a marriage/family conflict to solve, only the counselor part of the soul is needed. To resolve a war time issue, its avatar won't need these empathic  soul parts, its warrior and diplomacy compartments will do fine. When there's some urgent political conflict, it can be done human-size: the avatar will get a haircut, expensive clothes and the ability to lie. No real soul content is needed.

I estimate 5-6 avatar template versions per God will do fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Small Vessels Explode Prematurely (SVEP)**

The internal combustion engine is powered by explosions. The engine must be strong enough to contain the explosions without blowing apart itself. This prevents you building a 100kW engine the size of a grain of rice. No material is strong enough for such a small amount to resist the engine forces.  You cannot lower the stress on the engine without lowering the power of the engine.

God souls are very powerful. Their *heavenly aura* extends inside the body and exerts a large stress on their host. A human sized host only lasts a few days before their blood vessels start to burst and their skin necrotizes and they die an horrible death due to energy overflow. This is bad for morale among the god's followers.

The 25 ft avatar is about 64 times the mass. The energy overflow is spread out enough that the body can repair itself faster than it degrades. The heavenly aura is still detectable. But this time it is pleasant to followers rather than debilitating.